# Get revision numbers of root entity and their entities in collections

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

At the moment I am experimenting with the envers library in our application for integration. Whenever I do an getRevisions I only get the revisions for the root entity.

However I expect Envers to be able to get the revisions for the entities in the enclosed collections as well. I tried some custom queries but aren't able to combine the two together via a join or something else.

The entities are as follow:

**Entity: form**

```
@Audited
@Entity(name = "Form")
@DisplayProperty(displayProperty1 = "name")
public class Form extends IdentityIdEntity<Integer> {

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapKey(name = "id")
    private Map<Integer, FormElement> elements = new HashMap<Integer, FormElement>();

}
```

**Entity: FormElement**

```
@Audited
@Entity(name = "FormElement")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DisplayProperty(displayProperty1 = "name")
public abstract class FormElement extends TranslatableIdentityIdEntity<Integer, FormElementTranslation> implements
        Comparable<FormElement> {

        @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String name;

}
```

**Service: FormVersioningService**

```
public List<Number> findVersionsOfForm(Form form) {
        AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession());

        logger.info(auditReader.getRevisions(Form.class, form.getId()).toString());

        List resultList = auditReader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(FormElement.class, false, true)
                .addProjection(AuditEntity.revisionNumber()).add(AuditEntity.property("form_id").eq(form.getId()))
                .getResultList();
        logger.info(resultList);

        return null;

    }
```

The first log returns:

> INFO: [16, 19, 20, 24]

The second returns:

> INFO: [24, 25]

But I'd like to get the following result:

> INFO: [16, 19, 20, 24, 25]

I'm using Hibernate 3.5.6 and at the moment it isn't possible to upgrade to a new version, so I'm searching for a solution within this version.

Any help is welcome and will be appreciated

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529982/how-to-retrieve-the-audited-revision-of-relations